# Efficiently resize two numpy arrays to the lesser of the two

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do the following more efficiently:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([-1,-2,-3,-4], np.single)
array2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], np.single)
minLength = min(len(array1),len(array2))
array1.resize(minLength)
array2.resize(minLength)
print(array1)
print(array2)
```

Which would produce the following arrays:

```
[-1. -2. -3. -4.]
[1. 2. 3. 4.]
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: `array1 = array1[:len(array2)]` and `array2 = array2[:len(array1)]` will do what you need. Slice both arrays to the size of the other, effectively only re-sizing the larger one.

Comment: Is this a bottleneck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "better" way i can think of in python is for you to not try and resize the one that is already the smallest, but the `resize` method probably already does that. So in that case, the answer would be a no.
Obs: mayybeeee give a try to numpy and/or cupy?

Comment: @not_speshal, `no` is a fine answer even if it's short.  `resize` is in-place.  I did few time tests.  Less than a microsec.  But slice is faster.  In any case this is not a bottleneck.